# How to import all #include in c++?

Tags: c++

I was making a C++ program, and I was trying to import all with `#include`.
But what I tried didn't work. I think I might be getting a bit confused with Python's `from {module} import *` function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <*>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << Hello! << endl;
    return 0
}
```

So then, I opened up cmd and typed in:

```
c++ test.cpp -o test.exe
```

And this is the error I get...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\thoma>cd Desktop

C:\Users\thoma\Desktop>c++ test.cpp -o test.exe
test.cpp:1:13: fatal error: c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\*: Invalid argument
 #include <*>
             ^
compilation terminated.

C:\Users\thoma\Desktop>
```

My compiler is MinGW. Any help or answers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that.  `#include` each header you need separately.

Comment: Don't. It's very bad practice.

Comment: c++ is "you dont pay for what you dont use", so dont expect anything like that to ever be possible ;)

Comment: `find / -type f -name '*.h' -o -name '*.hpp' | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/#include <\1>/" > master_header.h` Have fun.

Comment: Sooner or later you'll stumble across how to do this, at least for G++-based compilers. Refrain from using it. It kills code portability, slows your compile times (Which is funny because if you use it for the intended purpose, it speeds up compilation) and adds tens of thousands of identifiers to your code. Add `using namespace std;` to it and you have a minefield to wade through and debug. It's not fun.

Comment: @user4581301: Happened already :(

Comment: @ChristianHackl Inevitable and forces me to waste a downvote

Comment: @user2079303: That misses the Standard headers, as they don't _have_ extensions. E.g. `<iostream>` and `<vector>`.

Comment: @MSalters They won't be missed if user has stdlibc++, since it has `bits/stdc++.h` which includes all standarad headers. Still, that means my `master_header.h` isn't portable after all :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#include <*>` is not C++, and there is no comparable feature to use. You must explicitly specify every header you need. This is a *good* thing. Get used to it.

You should also get rid of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Agree with the first sentence but second sentence about removing include to `using namespace std;` would immedialy lead to other compilation failures in the OP code. 
Deciding to use `using` directive or fully qualified namespace is more guided with local coding rule and/or probability of name collision

Comment: @sandwood: Of course it would lead to compilation failures. The OP would hopefully understand them and fix the code, and if not, ask about more details. It is extremely obvious here, given the question itself, that the OP uses "using namespace std" for no good reason.

Answer (score 8):

1. C++ is not Python.

   Do you mean Python's `from module import *`? Because that's different to what the C++ version you suggested would do (if it existed, which it doesn't), and anyway
2. Header files are not modules.

   C++ doesn't really have modules. You can organize your directory structure and build system into logical modules, but you have to do that yourself.

   The include directive itself though, is a textual operation: it just pastes the contents of the named file in place of the directive. There is no module scope, it's just ... *there*.
3. If your suggested syntax did work (which, again, it doesn't) - it would include *all* files. Not all .h files, but just ... everything. There isn't a required filename extension for C++ (I've seen .h, .hpp, .hxx, .cpp, .cxx and .C as well as a few rarer ones) so there would be no implicit filter on the wildcard.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you are confused here. With *#include* you really include a file. That means, the compiler takes the files contents and puts then and the position of your *#include-statement*. Every include in your code extends your file. That means the compiler has more work todo. If you would include *all* files, your compiler offers, that would be way to much. C++ include-system is something else than pythons module-system. So you have to include those files you really want. What you could do is, you can make a header file where you put those includes which you need often, and then you only include this header file. Your compiler would then include the files you included there. Example:

```
// includes.hpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// ...
```

And here is how you could use that:

```
// main.cpp
#include "includes.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string some_text = "Hello there";
    std::cout << some_text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please note also, don't use using namespace in a header file. Every header which includes this header would also get this using namespace statement. That can yield to problems in the future. I don't use it in code files neither. You can use using on specific parts of the namespace. But that is another topic. Maybe just google for *using namespace* problems.

What is important to say here. Even if you save some work with such include headers. Use them with attention. Like i said, include really copies text and so your compiler has more todo. Therefore your compilation time increases. In some cases this is a good solution, but most of the time it is better to include the parts you really need. In many cases, you don't even need to include headers, but you would use forward declarations. Just try to keep that in mind for the future.